# reading, grouping, finding average

Tags: python

I am new dummy to python...please help me in the following problem

I have a data in *.txt format as 4 colums `name|items| a1| a2|`, here I am interested only in 3rd and 4th column. Items column goes like a set `[1,1]`, `[12,12,2]` etc., I need to open the text file, read the file and group all similar items colums in one array, find the maximum of that array, and then take an average of all the arrays which are formed with similar items. Finally I will get 1 value which is average of the individual maximum in an array.

eg., `items [1,1]= [55,66]`

greatest of items `[1,1]` is `66`

items `[12, 12]` = `[56 89 88]`

greatest of items `[12, 12,2]` is `89`

item `[23 23 23]` = `[45, 33, 33.5]`

greatest of items `[23 23 23]` is `45`

average = maximum of items(`[1,1]+[12, 12]+........+[23 23 23]`) = (`66+89+...+45/ n`) = `x`

where n is the total no: of similar items, for instance here it's 6.

> > > ## name    items    a1       a2
> > >
> > > ```
> > > sty1    1      12      55
> > > ```
> >
> > ```
> > sty1    1      2       66
> >
> > sty1   12       5      56
> >
> > sty1   12       12     89
> >
> > sty1   12       2     88
> >
> > sty1   2      5      78
> >
> > sty1   31      5      45
> >
> > sty1   31      1      45
> >
> > sty1   31      3      45   
> >
> > sty1   31      8      45
> >
> > sty1   4      23     45
> >
> > sty1   4      12     45
> >
> > sty1   23      31     45
> > ```
>
> ```
> sty1   23      1      33 
>
> sty1   23      2      33.5
> ```

Comment: How far have you gotten so far?  Your question has several steps, each of which could be considered a separate question.

Comment: 1.  Please summarize your test data.  Too much detail is confusing.  2.  Please post some summary of what you've attempted so far.  "Please help me" means "please help me fix what I've already tried and can't get to work."

Comment: i struck with, how to group only similar items ? like  [1,1]= [55,66] ; [12, 12] = [56 89 88] etc., i don't know how to group only similar.

Comment: @pythonbeginer: (1) Use "I" when referring to yourself -- good grammar helps everyone to read and understand your question.  (2) Summarize your data.  (3) Post some summary of what you've done so far.  (3) **update** your question with the **specific** thing that confuses you. (4) Please explain why the first line of data becomes [1,1]=[55,66].  That makes no sense.  Please do not add comments.  Please fix your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open("...")

d = {}

for line in f:
    x = line.split()
    if len(x) == 4: #skip empty lines
        k = x[1]
        v = float(x[3])
        if not k in d: d[k] = v
        elif v > d[k]: d[k] = v #because we only need max of values

f.close()

sm = sum(d.values())

print d
print sm
print sm / len(d)

>>> 
{'12': 89.0, '23': 45.0, '31': 45.0, '1': 66.0, '2': 78.0, '4': 45.0}
368.0
61.3333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some sections from the Python tutorial you may find helpful:

- [Reading and writing files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- [Using python as a calculator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator)
- [Data structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)